# ArcObjects add multiple inputs to GeoProcessor

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, vb.net

I am trying to send multiples input features to the Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessor (to do an Intersect). I am doing this because I can't add the layer path since one of them is from ArcSDE. The example on the ESRI website is incomplete:

[Building a custom geoprocessing function tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000049w000000.htm)

```
[VB.NET]
' Multivalue parameter of Feature Layers/Feature Classes.'
Dim inputParameter As IGPParameterEdit3 = New GPParameterClass()
Dim inputType As IGPDataType = New GPFeatureLayerTypeClass()

Dim mvType As IGPMultiValue = New GPMultiValueClass()
mvType.MemberDataType = inputType

Dim mvValue As IGPMultiValue = New GPMultiValueClass()
mvValue.MemberDataType = inputType

inputFeatures.Name = "input_features"
inputFeatures.DisplayName = "Input Features"
inputFeatures.ParameterType = esriGPParameterType.esriGPParameterTypeRequired
inputFeatures.Direction = esriGPParameterDirection.esriGPParameterDirectionInput
inputFeatures.DataType = CType(mvType, IGPDataType)
inputFeatures.Value = CType(mvValue, IGPValue)

parameters.Add(inputFeatures)
```

There is no code to actually add the feature layer to the input features list. I tried to add my feature layer with :

```
mvValue.AddValue(lFeatureLayer)
```

and I got a invalid COM interface cast exception. What is the real way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **create** a new geoprocessing tool like in your example, then you do not add the layer yourself. This is doing the tool for you during running it.

But I think you want to **consume** an already existing tool (like intersect). This is explained in [How to run a geoprocessing tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003rr000000)

Comment: I ended up doing something else because it doesn't work. Like I said, I must use the IfeatureLayer object because I can't use a path for ArcSDE. Anyway, I don't need an answer anymore. Thanks!